# Jquery.load returns 206 Partial Content and no content shows

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling `$('#help').load('http://recaptcha.net/popuphelp/');` but it returns 206 Partial Content and doesn't fill the div with the help information.

I think it has something to do with cross-domain request limitations.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Is an `<iframe>` an option? Seems like the simplest approach here.

Comment: Another approach (probably not the most practical) is a server side proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Nick is correct. The reason for the error is because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
Basically you cannot make cross-domain requests in an ajax call.

In this case the best solution is to use an iFrame.